# keyspace and tables not replicating across data centre in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to create cassandra cluster. For that I have a single node data centres
One data center is named DC1 and the other is DC2. Hence there are 2 single node data center. I followed the steps given here
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/initialize/initializeMultipleDS.html

Since I have single node data center, so my seed will be a single machine. I can do ndoetool -h  status to both the machines. I created a keyspace like this

```
CREATE KEYSPACE sams WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1': '1', 'DC2': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

and a table like

```
CREATE TABLE apikey (   appname text,   appkey text,   PRIMARY KEY ((appname), appkey) );
```

I create keyspace and table in one data centre. This should get replicated on the other machine but it does not replicate. There are no keyspaces shown on the other data center neither any tables.

What am I missing here?

Adding nodetool output

```
nodetool -h cassandra1 status
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address          Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  100.117.100.107  178.28 KB  256     100.0%            0c5da294-2a86-472d-98ec-857ed5140417  RAC1


 nodetool -h cassandra2 status
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  100.117.150.55  162.94 KB  256     ?       9f3e49f6-debc-4a9c-ba93-bc65b3851a48  RAC1
```

Comment: Can you add output of `nodetool status`?

Comment: Updated the desciption

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have accidentally set up two independent clusters rather than a single cluster that spans two data centers.

Make sure in cassandra.yaml that both nodes have the same cluster_name and that both have the same list of ip's for "- seeds:".  Since you only have two nodes, I'd list both ip's as the seeds rather than just one.

If the nodes have joined the same cluster, then it should show both of them when you run nodetool status.